# Form validation with jquery when in form doesn't exist input with class 'error'

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form:

```
<form id="FormId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"validate input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"validate input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"bg-datepicker">​
</form>
```

here I add/remove error class

```
   $("#ButtonId").click(function () {
                     $("#FormId input[type=text].validate").filter(function () {
                         this.value == '' ? $(this).addClass('error') : 
                     $(this).removeClass('error')
                     });
            });
```

How to validate this form when in form doesn't exist inputs with class 'error'

Comment: Have you tried the validate plugin? http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: Please stop tagging your questions with [tag:jquery-validate] when they have nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure what actaully you need.. but sounds like.. you need to check the length of the element and check if exists or not..

```
 if($('.error').length == 0){ //check if there is element with class error
    //element with error class does not exists
 }else{
    //it exists
 }
```

however , there are lots of already built jquery validation plugins. easy to use without much of codes .. have a look [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation)